# Как прокрутить GridView на весь экран?

Tags: android

GridView отверстан на нижнюю половину экрана, вверху располагаются картинка с описанием(статичные), но когда возникает необходимость прокрутить GridView, он прокручивается только на пол нижнего экрана. 
Как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутки GridView верхние элементы страницы плавно убирались, а грид становился прокручиваемым на весь экран?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut

Тут есть ответ. Все решают scrollview + усовершенствованный gridview ))

Answer (score 1):

Положите в `ScrollView` те только `GridView` но и `ImageView`. Только это делается с помощью `LinearLayout`

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>

    <ImageView>
    </ImageView>

    <GridView>
    </GridView>

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: А разве не будет проблем с тем, что GridView тоже скролящийся и начнёт конфликтовать со ScrollView?